# ENS domain expiring and renewal

Tags: ens

From what I understand, ENS is less than one year old at the time of this post. 
So, it follows that no domain has expired for any owner. No person has experience renewing the rights to their ENS domain.

Do expired domains go back into the auction like the first owner of the domain had to win in the first place? Or is there a first right for the current owner of a domain has to extend the expiration out for as many years into the future as he is willing to pay?

I am afraid to make the mistake that my free association understanding of what I imagine the process should be is not actually the case in the real world. I'm afraid to use ENS because I see no confirmation that I have a means to keep the domain after it expires. I am concerned that if I have a good domain then it is very easy to lose that domain at the expiration date.

Are there any sources available that address these concerns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expiration date is when the permanent registrar is expected to be deployed. Once that happens, you have to do a manual transfer to the new registrar.

source: [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/78nnlq/ens_expiration_date/)

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. I was misunderstanding. I believed that was when I lost the rights to the domain and needed to renew my ownership.

Comment: So assuming that once the permanent registrar is deployed and I've got my existing .eth domain transferred over, will a yearly fee like with a traditional .com domain apply? If so, how much am I expected to pay? Same as the amount I bought it for?

Comment: @JaySidri No yearly fee. You just spend gas when updating the resolver or changing the address the domain needs to point to.

Answer (score 2):

The permanent registrar will eliminate the auction system, but will have an annual cost that you will need to pay to keep your domains. The cost will be the same for all domains. To discourage squatting it will be set similar to that of DNS names, possible around 10 USD per year. The price may be adjusted over time, but you can register as many years in advance as you want if you're worried about future price changes or forgetting.

source: [State of the ENS talk by Nick Johnson, ENS core team (Oct 30, 2018)](https://slideslive.com/38911737/state-of-the-ens)
[image]

Comment: Any info on how the ENS contract is governed? By a DAO?